# How to use AWS CDK FindInMap to set property of number type?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm building a CloudFormation template with properties which should be set with different value according to stage (e.g., beta, prod). The property's type is number. However, the Fn.FindInMap returns string token. So how to use FindInMap to set such property of number type?

This is for AWS CDK Java language APIs.

This is code section of Mapping:

```
Mapping writeCapacityMapping = new Mapping(parent, "TableWriteCapacityMapping", MappingProps.builder()
                .withMapping(ImmutableMap.of(
                        Stage.beta.name(), ImmutableMap.of(
                                "min", 5,
                                "max", 100),
                        Stage.prod.name(), ImmutableMap.of(
                                "min", 400,
                                "max", 1200)))
                .build());
```

This is code section trying to get value from mapping by stage parameter  and assign to properties (minCapacity and maxCapacity) which requires Number type.

```
String minCapacity = Fn.findInMap("TableWriteCapacityMapping", stageParameter.getValueAsString(), "min");
String maxCapacity = Fn.findInMap("TableWriteCapacityMapping", stageParameter.getValueAsString(), "max");

ScalableTargetProps props = ScalableTargetProps.builder()
                .withMinCapacity(Integer.valueOf(minCapacity))
                .withMaxCapacity(Integer.valueOf(maxCapacity))
                .build();
```

The expected the CloudFormation template is:

```
Mappings:
  WriteCapacityMap:
    beta:
      min: 5
      max: 100
    prod:
      min: 400
      max: 1200

TableWriteCapacityScalableTarget:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MinCapacity:
        Fn::FindInMap: [WriteCapacityMap, { Ref: "Stage" }, min]
      MaxCapacity:
        Fn::FindInMap: [WriteCapacityMap, { Ref: "Stage" }, max]
```

However, the following exception will be thrown because minCapacity or maxCapacity are token string: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${Token[TOKEN.14]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is useful for you, I'd like to share my solution - using AWS CloudFormation layer library.

As mentioned in AWS CDK docs [1], under the hood, CDK constructs are implemented using AWS CloudFormation libraries which are available in the `CfnXxx` classes in each library. For advanced use cases and gaps between CDK and CloudFormation, it might be required to use these CloudFormation libraries.

For example:

- **AWS CDK construct**: The `minCapacity` property in `software.amazon.awscdk.services.applicationautoscaling.ScalableTarget` accepts parameter of `Number` type.

  ```java
    void setMinCapacity(final java.lang.Number value);
  ```
- **AWS CloudFormation library**: The `minCapacity` property in `software.amazon.awscdk.services.applicationautoscaling.CfnScalableTargetProps`
  `CfnScalableTargetProps` can be set with `Number` or `Token`.

  ```java
    void setMinCapacity(final java.lang.Number value);
    void setMinCapacity(final software.amazon.awscdk.Token value);
  ```

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/CDK/latest/userguide/cloudformation.html

Comment: Another example for using `CfnRule` and `CfnRule.TargetProperty` to set CloudWatch Event Rule with SQS Queue - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/1786